# trying to use owncloud but it says some php modules not installed

Tags: linux, owncloud

I get this error when trying to enter to http://localhost/index.php

```
PHP module zip not installed.

Please ask your server administrator to install the module.
PHP module dom not installed.

Please ask your server administrator to install the module.
PHP module XMLWriter not installed.

Please ask your server administrator to install the module.
PHP module XMLReader not installed.

Please ask your server administrator to install the module.
PHP module intl not installed.

Please ask your server administrator to install the module.
PHP module libxml not installed.

Please ask your server administrator to install the module.
PHP module mb multibyte not installed.

Please ask your server administrator to install the module.
PHP module GD not installed.

Please ask your server administrator to install the module.
PHP module SimpleXML not installed.

Please ask your server administrator to install the module.
PHP module cURL not installed.

Please ask your server administrator to install the module.
PHP modules have been installed, but they are still listed as missing?

Please ask your server administrator to restart the web server.
```

where the owncloud is installed, I tried this command:

```
apt-get install -y apache2 mariadb-server libapache2-mod-php7.0     openssl php-imagick php7.0-common php7.0-curl php7.0-gd     php7.0-imap php7.0-intl php7.0-json php7.0-ldap php7.0-mbstring     php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-mysql php7.0-pgsql php-smbclient php-ssh2     php7.0-sqlite3 php7.0-xml php7.0-zip
```

but it gave me some strange error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.1 (>= 1:10.1.34-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have no idea what to do... I searched all the internet and didn't find an answer...

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, there are several PHP modules you need to install:

```
apt install -y apache2 mariadb-server libapache2-mod-php7.0 \
php7.0-gd php7.0-json php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl \
php7.0-intl php7.0-mcrypt php-imagick \
php7.0-zip php7.0-xml php7.0-mbstring
```

For the second part, it seems that you have a held package on apt. You need to find out which package is held:

```
 sudo aptitude why-not mariadb-server
```

There are several reasons why a package is held, what to do depends on why it's held. Generally, once you know why it is held and you fix the reason why you can unhold it:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold package_name
```

If you have no clue why it is held you can try to fix broken dependencies, but this can be bad if there is a real reason why it must be held:

```
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server --fix-missing --fix-broken
```

If you are on a hosting it might be held by your hosting so you basically can skip the mariadb install since it seems to be installed on a previous version.